# Хочу отловить момент перед загрузкой файла с помощью input(сделать расширение, которое будет иметь такую возможность)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, webkit

Возможно ли это технически? Полагаю, что нет, а единственная возможность - апгрейд браузера / создание своего. Хочу отлавливать и предлагать совершенно свои варианты. Сколько искал инфу - не нашел ни одного упоминания даже близко. Скорее всего не так задаю вопрос.

Если быть совсем точным, то требуется остановить открытие выбора файла, а вместо него сделать свой вариант, но если его пропустить, то продолжить стандартный сценарий

Answer (score 2):

> Если быть совсем точным, то требуется остановить открытие выбора файла, а вместо него сделать свой вариант, но если его пропустить, то продолжить стандартный сценарий

В общем случае, будет достаточно добавить (как можно раньше!) слушатель события `click` на `window`, обрабатывающий события на этапе их захвата (распространения события "вниз" по DOM-дереву):

```js
const handler = evt => {
  if (!evt.target.matches('input[type="file"]')) return;  // если событие было возбуждено не файловым инпутом, игнорируем
  const confirmed = confirm('Правда хотите загрузить что-то в злые интернеты?');
  if (!confirmed) {                                       // тут может быть любое условие отмены обычной обработки события
    evt.preventDefault();                                 // так предотвращается обычная обработка события
    /* ....здесь могут быть какие-либо доп. действия: "сделать свой вариант".... */
  }
};
window.addEventListener('click', handler, true);          // третий аргумент здесь включает обработку событий на их захвате (а по-умолчанию, слушатель вызывается на этапе всплытия)
```

```html
<input type="file">
```

Обработка событий таким образом, нужна для достижения двух целей:

- повышение вероятности успешного перехвата события
  *<sub>// фаза захвата события предшествует фазе его всплытия - а т.к. `window` находится "наверху" дерева DOM, на этапе захвата его обработчики срабатывают раньше добавленных на дочерние узлы</sub>*
- избежание необходимости добавлять обработчик каждому элементу
  *<sub>// применяемая тут техника называется делегированием обработки событий. Ее плюсом (важным для данной задачи) является то, что так будут обрабатываться события возникающие и на динамически добавляемых элементах - а не только на присутствующих в DOM на момент выполнения скрипта</sub>*

Комменты в примере сдвинуты чтобы не сильно мешали восприятию кода - для более удобного их прочтения, советую развернуть пример на всю страницу.

---

**Что почитать по теме:**
[Введение в события](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) (MDN) - большая и подробная вводная статья по обработке DOM-событий, ориентирована на новичков;
[Всплытие и <s>погружение</s> захват](https://learn.javascript.ru/bubbling-and-capturing) (learn.javascript.ru) - именно о распространении событий. В статье повсеместно используется некорректная терминология (помимо слишком вольного перевода "capturing", есть и другие ляпы), но сама суть механизмов распространения там передана верно.

Comment: В расширениях для Chromium, обработчики событий следует добавлять в [контент-скриптах](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/), а не в фоновых (сервис-воркерах расширения), потому что фоновые скрипты не имеют доступа к DOM страниц.

Comment: Нет, Не то я имел в виду. Если сказать еще точнее, то я хочу загружать картинки с буфера обмена для любого сайта, установив одно расширение. Видел подобное в опере, но в качестве расширения не нашел. Потому пробую изобрести велосипед. То есть перед выполнением открытия окна загрузки, появится свое окошко, в котором я выберу скриншот из буфера, и конкретно он загрузится в тот самый файлообменник, который выбирал я изначально. Так хотел, но не подумал, что меня можно не понять

Comment: @jorlyf, ответить можно только на то, о чем спрашивают. Вот и тут: о чем ты спросил, на то и получил ответ :) Если этот вопрос должен был быть о другом - то в данном случае уже поздно менять его тему. Для получения ответов о чем-то другом, надо открыть новый вопрос (и это "что-то другое" описать _точнее и подробнее_: какая конкретно задача заключена в этом настойчивом "хочу", какие именно трудности возникли при попытке ее решения, и какой код ты написал пытаясь ее решить. Такая информация в вопросе сильно поможет и тебе, и всем отвечающим).

Comment: @jorlyf, проще говоря, чем больше технических подробностей добавишь в вопросе - тем точнее будут ответы на него. А к буферу обмена, вроде нет такого уровня доступа в JS (чтобы что-то из буфера выбирать)... скрипты ведь могут "дотянуться" только до того что получает браузер, а он из буфера только одно значение считать может (непосредственно вставляемое юзером). Чтение содержимого буфера **без** действия пользователя, запрещено политиками безопасности: чтобы считать, надо запросить пермишн, и это вызывает противный диалог подтверждения...

Answer (score 0):

Смог найти частичную документацию. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Events
и написать что-то подобное

```
   <script>
        function handleChooseFile(input) {
            console.log('отловил');

        }

        const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="file"]');
        console.log(inputs);
        for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            const input = inputs[i];
            input.addEventListener('click', () => handleChooseFile(input));
            
            console.log(input);
        }
    </script>
```